# Gradle Output missing generated META-INF file

Tags: gradle, log4j2, javac

I have a project using Log4j2. When I build it with Javac from the command line, my build-output includes a `Log4j2Properties.dat` file under the `META-INF` directory.

Note, that this Log4j2Properties.dat file is **not** in the source directory, it's generated at build-time by some magic inside javac.

However, when using a JavaCompile task in Gradle, my build output only includes class files.

How do I persuade it to also generate and include the `Log4j2Properties.dat` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I finally worked this out. Posting here for future people (including myself ;)):

The problem was that Gradle was more strict than Javac in running annotation processors, which were needed to generate my missing file. In this case I simply had to add the Log4j annotation processor into my dependencies -> annotationProcessor list.